# Solving Binary Bomb Phase 5

Tags: debugging, assembly, gdb, reverse-engineering, x86

I am getting stuck on phase 5 of my binary bomb assignment.  I am trying to figure out what loop is going on so I can figure out the two inputs that I need.  Any help is appreciated!  Here is the assembly code:

```
Dump of assembler code for function phase_5:
   0x08048edc <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x08048edd <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048edf <+3>: push   %esi
   0x08048ee0 <+4>: push   %ebx
   0x08048ee1 <+5>: sub    $0x20,%esp
   0x08048ee4 <+8>: lea    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048ee7 <+11>:    mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
   0x08048eeb <+15>:    lea    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048eee <+18>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
   0x08048ef2 <+22>:    movl   $0x804a5ac,0x4(%esp)
   0x08048efa <+30>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048efd <+33>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048f00 <+36>:    call   0x8048894 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
   0x08048f05 <+41>:    cmp    $0x1,%eax
   0x08048f08 <+44>:    jg     0x8048f0f <phase_5+51>
   0x08048f0a <+46>:    call   0x8049351 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048f0f <+51>:    mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x08048f12 <+54>:    and    $0xf,%eax
   0x08048f15 <+57>:    mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
   0x08048f18 <+60>:    cmp    $0xf,%eax
   0x08048f1b <+63>:    je     0x8048f46 <phase_5+106>
   0x08048f1d <+65>:    mov    $0x0,%ecx
   0x08048f22 <+70>:    mov    $0x0,%edx
   0x08048f27 <+75>:    mov    $0x804a500,%ebx
   0x08048f2c <+80>:    add    $0x1,%edx
   0x08048f2f <+83>:    mov    (%ebx,%eax,4),%eax
   0x08048f32 <+86>:    add    %eax,%ecx
   0x08048f34 <+88>:    cmp    $0xf,%eax
   0x08048f37 <+91>:    jne    0x8048f2c <phase_5+80>
   0x08048f39 <+93>:    mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
   0x08048f3c <+96>:    cmp    $0xf,%edx
   0x08048f3f <+99>:    jne    0x8048f46 <phase_5+106>
   0x08048f41 <+101>:   cmp    %ecx,-0x10(%ebp)
   0x08048f44 <+104>:   je     0x8048f4b <phase_5+111>
=> 0x08048f46 <+106>:   call   0x8049351 <explode_bomb>
   0x08048f4b <+111>:   add    $0x20,%esp
   0x08048f4e <+114>:   pop    %ebx
   0x08048f4f <+115>:   pop    %esi
   0x08048f50 <+116>:   pop    %ebp
   0x08048f51 <+117>:   ret
```

My inputs must be two decimals based on the result of `x/s 0x804a5ac` on line <+22>.

On line <+60>, there is a compare that is making sure that my first input is not 15.  (Edited this line based on the first comment)

It seems like the loop is forcing me to run 15 times with the counter being %edx on line <+80>.

Comment: It's not a `jge` jump at `+63`, it's a `je` jump. It checks that the input is not equal to 15, not that it's less than 15.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but only differs in minor detail.

Comment: @Jester thank you! That helped me figure it out!

Comment: @Jester, I need 15 reputation :(